# Error when i convert Android module from 'app' to 'library'

Tags: android, plugins, module

there is the error message:
`* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app.main'.

> Transforms with scopes '[SUB_PROJECTS, SUB_PROJECTS_LOCAL_DEPS, EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES]' cannot be appliedto library projects.`

when i build an project with 'app.main' plugin,then i want to transform it from app to library 
i have already modify as above:

[image]

so it cause this error.help me! thx!!!

Answer (score 0):

I've find the answer! that is you should rename the module from app.xxx to lib.xxx 
in addition. that's it